# How can i disable scroll, if clicked survey next button

Tags: scroll

Any idea why all of a sudden every time you click on one of the answers, the whole screen moves to the top?

Survey Link: https://app.grillomarketing.com/v2/preview/Gg3ERkkv4fCAUmGor5pL

Answer (score 0):

```
function disableScroll() {
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
  
        // if any scroll is attempted, set this to the previous value
        window.onscroll = function() {
            window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        };
}
  
function enableScroll() {
    window.onscroll = function() {};
}
```

This code will disable scroll fully but you might have some event listener that scrolls to the element when button is clicked.

[code source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily-using-javascript/)

Comment: var nextBTN = document.querySelector('.ghl-survey-form button.ghl-mobile-next.ghl-next-button.ghl-button');
nextBTN.addEventListener('click', disableScroll);

function disableScroll() {
 // Get the current page scroll position
 scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 (scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft),
  // if any scroll is attempted, set this to the previous value
  (window.onscroll = function () {
   window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
  });
} 

Not Working